# Keep the navbar width same while scrolling Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a `nav-bar` on my page with following code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-lower" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="container collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

It works fine and just like i want it to except for its `width` when i scroll.
I want its width to be same as the width of my `body` tag on that page but when i scroll it adds a little extra `width` on the right.
Look at the screenshots below for more clear understanding

[image]

[image]

I tried changing the `container` class and adding it to `<nav class="container"...` but that doesn't fix it.

Comment: You should post an actual working example Snippet (HTML/CSS/JS) of your code. What you've posted does not clearly illustrate the issue. [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fiddle showing the navbar never adds width [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/8dqd3xzd/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-lower" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="container collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

And if you want to add width you need to do the following

Your need to add class when you scroll

set your original nav class to have a margin and set it outside of the container and then set your scrolled to to not have the margin

```
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-lower" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="container collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Then add

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('nav').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 1);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I misread your original question I edited the answer see if that works

Comment: its works fine in demo you attached and so it should work fine on my page but i think there is some other conflict on my page here. And this is second navbar i am using on my page besides the main top navbar.

Comment: Ya there is some kind of other conflict because as far as I know bootstraps navbars dont move when scrolling at least I have never heard of it before.  If it is the second navbar you may have it wrapped in another container or something that you don't realize you can try and take it out of all containers and maybe add the css margin: 0; to the navbar-default.  But there is probably something else besides the navbar doing it.